# Laravel 5.2 Get date_diff of data each rows using eloquent method

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, laravel-5

I want to get the date difference from date today and set as reference while querying on database each rows to count the days. How to construct it in laravel-eloquent way? Thanks!

```
$query ="SELECT unix_timestamp(NOW()) - unix_timestamp(created_at) AS time_diff from users WHERE trial=1";
$result=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{ 
 $diff= $row['time_diff']
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `selectRaw` in [laravel Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#selects)

```
DB::table('users')
->selectRaw('unix_timestamp(NOW()) - unix_timestamp(created_at) AS time_diff')
->where('trial',1)
->get();
```

or you want use [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent)

```
Model::select(DB::raw('unix_timestamp(NOW()) - unix_timestamp(created_at) AS time_diff'))
->where('trial',1)
->get();
```